# Unity3d Animation - How to make the player to stay at the target position after the animation completes

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Created a simple animation to move a cube from `(0,0,0)` to `(5,0,0)`. 
When the animation stops, cube is going back to `(0,0,0)`. How to make sure that the cube stays at `(5,0,0)` even after animation completes

Answer (score 1):

You could also checkout the [`AnimatorState WriteDefault`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-State.html) value.

> Whether or not the AnimatorStates writes back the default values for properties that are not animated by its Motion.

By default it is enabled so if the State is left the Animator resets to the default values of your inanimated objects.

If you disable this value than the last state stays persistent although the state is left or the Animator disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using simple Animator state machine with `idle`, `moveLeft` and `moveRight` states and appropriate `triggers`!!!